# How to match array with array in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

hi
i have an array like this:

> ```
> array1 [00] = 01,KSE
> array1 [01] = 04,NCEL
> array1 [02] = 06,LSE
> ```

I have a second array (`codeArray`) that has about 50 elements. All elements are '01' or '04' or '06'.

Now i have to compare both arrays & array1 have to return a name (KSE or NCEL or LSE) against the code so how can i do it?
Help plz

Thanx in advance

`array1` is a response that i am receiving from server & `codeArray` is also coming from server thats why both arrays are dynamic & can have any value but all the values in `codeArray` will exist in `array1`

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: i want to compare both arrays & if codeArray have 3 elements & they are 01 01 & 06 then array1 should return KSE KSE & LSE.

Comment: array1[0] = ?? What value is 01,KSE is this string ???

Comment: Question does not make any sense. Also, who is plz and how can I help him?

Comment: @vito u r right array1[0] = 01,KSE & array1 [1] = 04,NCEL.
infect i got a string that was @"01,KSE;04,NCEL;06,LSE" then i separate it & saved it in an array

Comment: what do you want to do can you explain more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using C arrays or NSArray? I will assume NSArray, ok? Sorry I am having a hard time understanding your question.

```
-(NSArray*)decodeArray:(NSArray*)codeArray keyArray:(NSArray*)array1
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ;
    for( NSString * string in array1 )
    {
        NSArray * split = [ string componentsSeparatedByString:@"," ] ;
        [ dict setValue:[ split objectAtIndex:1 ] forKey:[ split objectAtIndex:0 ] ] ;
    }

    NSMutableArray * result = [ NSMutableArray array ] ;
    for( id item in codeArray )
    {
        [ result addObject:[ dict valueForKey:item ] ] ;
    }

    return result ;
}
```

Comment: you got the point what i need. but array1 can be changed & can have different values, not only these 3 values. Now we have to make it generic

Comment: :D thanx nielsbot for help you got my problem that is what i am looking for. So nice of you & COOL :)

Comment: since I did your homework for you you should check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
array1[0] = "01,KSE";
array1[1] = "04,NCEL";
array1[2] = "06,LSE";

if( [codeArray length] == 3 ) {
  if( ([codeArray[0] isEqualToString:@"01"] || [codeArray[0] isEqualToString:@"04"] ||
      [codeArray[0] isEqualToString:@"06"]) && ([codeArray[1] isEqualToString:@"01"] ||
      [codeArray[1] isEqualToString:@"04"] || [codeArray[1] isEqualToString:@"06"]) &&
      ([codeArray[2] isEqualToString:@"01"] || [codeArray[2] isEqualToString:@"04"] ||
      [codeArray[2] isEqualToString:@"06"]) )
           return @"KSE KSE & LSE";
```

This is all that I can answer on your question ...

Comment: array1 can have different codes not the same codes every time

Comment: No matter what values it can have because I compare  codeArray values and return KSE KSE & LSE

Comment: I mean that in array1 values can be increased there can also come "GSE" "DSE" with some codes